# How long does soil need to last?

Tags: halacha, time, trees, orla-revai, maseches-orla

If you move a tree with its soil, it's considered replanted (so the rules of *orla* kick in) unless it can live off of the soil you're moving it with. (Masechet Orla 1,3 see [Rambam.](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=106754&rid=7152)) Clearly "if it can live" doesn't mean "if it can live for the amount of time it takes to move the tree", as, well, it *does* love that long, or else it's dead. On the other hand, no tree will live *forever* in some unchanging body of soil. So for how long a life does "it can live" mean?

Comment: kind of a duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/orla-are-the-leaves-of-the-plant-included-in-the-prohibition#comment9601_7737

Comment: @DoubleAA, this question is of independent interest (independent of that question, I mean). I don't think we generally close even an exact duplicate if the thing it's a duplicate of is a comment.

Comment: msh210 I didn't vote to close, only a downvote for poor onsite research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [Alex's comment elsewhere](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7737) (which I only saw now), I discovered [the *Pische S'shuva*, *YD* 294:13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&pgnum=242&hilite=), who cites *Parach Mate Aharon* as saying the soil must last three years, and *Shivas Tziyon* as qualifying that that's only in *eretz Yisrael*: in *chutz laaretz*, he says, [where *safek orla* is permitted,] the soil must last "a few days".

Answer (score 5):

The [Pitchei Teshuva in Yoreh Deah 294 sk 13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=242) quotes a number of opionions but rules that in Israel where we rule stringently about doubts relating to orla, there must be enough dirt to survive three whole years; in the Diaspora, however, where we rule leniently about such doubts, it only needs to be enough dirt to last a couple of days.

[h/t Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/orla-are-the-leaves-of-the-plant-included-in-the-prohibition#comment9604_7737)